# characteristic system for the linear PDE when some partial derivatives does not appear

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

The first step to solve the linear Partial Differential Equation
$$
f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)\frac{\partial\omega(x_1,\dots,x_n)}{\partial x_1}+\cdots+f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)\frac{\partial\omega(x_1,\dots,x_n)}{\partial x_n}=0
$$
is to construct the following *characteristic system*
$$
\frac{dx_1}{f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)}=\frac{dx_2}{f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n)}=\cdots=\frac{dx_n}{f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)}
$$
What happens to the above characteristic system if some of $f_i$s are zero (i.e. not all $\partial\omega/\partial x_i$ for $i=1,\cdots,n$ does appear in the PDE)?

Comment: In this case you know nothing about $\frac{\partial\omega}{\partial x_i}$, therefore dependance $\omega$ of $x_i$ can be arbitrary.

Comment: If a variable (for example $x_k$) doesn't appear in the PDE you consider $x_k$ as a parameter, not as a variable. $\frac{dx_k}{f_k(x_1,...,x_n)}$ doesn't exist among the fractions. So, in first place the PDE can be solved without $x_k$. Finally each arbitrary constant appearing in the solution has to be replace by an arbitrary function of $x_k$.

Comment: Another approach : If a variable (for example $x_k$) doesn't appear in the PDE then $f_k(x_1,...,x_n)=0$. and $...=\frac{dx_k}{0}=...$ implies $dx_k=0$. The corresponding characteristic equation is : $x_k=c_k$=constant. Thus $x_k$ acts as a parameter, not as a variable.